# Opencv linking libraries

Tags: opencv

i have installed opencv 3.1.0 and i want to compile following program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "opencv/cv.h"
 #include "opencv/highgui.h"

 int main(void){
     return 0;
 }
```

but it returns `error:undefined reference` to `cvRound` and so on in header file `types_c.h`.

I know it must be a linking problem but the only libraries i can link are:
`opencv_world310.lib`, `opencv_world310d.lib`

I have already tried to link these but that doesn't solve the problem.
I m using a GNU GCC Compiler and dynamic libraries a link with mingw32-g++.exe.

According to some research in the internet i need to link libraries like:

```
`opencv_calib3d249d.lib`
 opencv_contrib249d.lib
 opencv_core249d.lib
 opencv_features2d249d.lib
 opencv_flann249d.lib
 opencv_gpu249d.lib
 opencv_highgui249d.lib
 opencv_imgproc249d.lib
 opencv_legacy249d.lib
 opencv_ml249d.lib
 opencv_nonfree249d.lib
 opencv_objdetect249d.lib
 opencv_ocl249d.lib
 opencv_photo249d.lib
 opencv_stitching249d.lib
 opencv_superres249d.lib
 opencv_ts249d.lib
  opencv_video249d.lib
 opencv_videostab249d.lib`
```

but those are not in my `lib` directory!

Comment: link only `opencv_world310.lib` in release, and `opencv_world310d.lib` in debug. Don't link both of them! Also you can use `#include <opencv.hpp>` to be sure to include all required headers. And don't use obsolete C headers (and don't use obsolete C code)!

Comment: It's unlikely anyone can help since you didn't say what platform you are using nor what command you are trying to use to compile and link.

Comment: i m using codeblocks and i created a project where i added the library opencv_world310.lib in linker setting at build options

Comment: the compiler is a GNU GCC Compiler and dynamic libraries are linked with mingw32-g++.exe